# Downloading file using C# HTTP GET

Tags: c#

How do I download a file using HTTP GET for C# 4.0 instead of the normal webclient.download?

Comment: What's wrong with `WebClient`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the a web browser request

Comment: That's what web client do actually. Also you can use socket for this

Comment: You can use HttpWebRequest, Sockets, TcpClient.. can you elaborate why WebClient cannot meet your requirements?

Comment: I need to emulate a mobile web browser HTTP 1.1 GET request to download a file since the site I'm downloading from only accepts mobile clients

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a GET request.  Are you looking to stream the response perhaps?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead("http://www.mypage.com")))
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: So i just save the hex info in request into a file with the desired extension?

Comment: Actually, at that point, you have the whole "file" as a String which you can save w/ any extension.  If your goal however, is to emulate a browser, you would do so by modifying your header to look like a mobile device request as in Rob's post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to emulate a web browser you can still can use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Just make sure to set the user agent.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

If you also need to set cookies in your request just extend the class and override the GetWebRequest() method.